# ADO.NET issue writing to Database

Tags: c#, database, ado.net

I'm trying to insert into a database with the code below, I've tried everything I can think of but when I check the table in the database nothing changes, what am I doing wrong?

P.S As you can see below, the name of the database is Stoichiometry.mdb, and the name of the table is Molecules.

Thanks

```
 con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Stoichiometry.mdb");
    adMol = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    adMol.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Molecules", con);

    dsHistory = new DataSet();
    con.Open();
    adMol.Fill(dsHistory, "Molecules");
    con.Close();

    DataRow data = dsHistory.Tables["Molecules"].NewRow();
    data["Formula"] = formula_;
    data["MolecularWeight"] = totalWeight_;
    adMol.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Molecules (Formula,"
                    + " MolecularWeight) " + "VALUES(@Formula, @MolecularWeight)", con);


    adMol.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Formula", OleDbType.VarChar, 250, "Formula");
    adMol.InsertCommand.Parameters["@Formula"].SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;
    adMol.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@MolecularWeight", OleDbType.Numeric, 20, "MolecularWeight");
    adMol.InsertCommand.Parameters["@MolecularWeight"].SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this line after adding parameters

```
adMol.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**UPDATE**

```
adMol.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Molecules (Formula," + " MolecularWeight) " + "VALUES(@Formula, @MolecularWeight)", con);
adMol.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Formula", OleDbType.VarChar, 250, "Formula");
adMol.InsertCommand.Parameters["@Formula"].SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;
adMol.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@MolecularWeight", OleDbType.Numeric, 20, "MolecularWeight");
adMol.InsertCommand.Parameters["@MolecularWeight"].SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;
adMol.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```